# Why does this C program print output "10" irrespective of the for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i=10;
  for (int i=1;i<=20;i++)
    i++;
    printf("%d",i); 
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand that why this C program always only prints the output as 10 irrespective of the condition that has been given in the for loop. I tried to execute it by making some changes in the for loop like `for (int i=1;i<=50;i++)`, but it returned the same output! What is the mistake here?

Comment: C is not Python.  Only the extra increment is in the loop.  Also, the `i` in the loop is a separate variable from the `i` outside the loop.  If you use GCC, add option `-Wshadow`.

Comment: Some versions of GCC would also warn about inconsistent indentation (or will do so if prodded — using `-Wall -Wextra` is probably sufficient).

Answer (score 5):

It is a `for` loop, so it increments according to what you write in its header : `i++` here. You don't need to increment `i` manually in the loop body by doing `i++` once more.

Further than that, if you declare a variable `i` before the loop, and write `for (int i=1;i<=20;i++)`, it declares another variable only for the scope of the loop. Since you didn't put any brackets around your loop code, the latter is only made of the line `i++`. Then, the `for` scope ends, and you print the "other" `i` variable, which you declared earlier, and initialized at 10.

Comment: The presence of two variables both called `i` is a key part of the diagnosis.

Comment: Compiling with extra warnings enabled such as with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` would diagnose this unexpected condition and thus help prevent such silly mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

This is what your code ***actually*** says, with some comments to illustrate

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=10;               // Variable i is declared (=10)
    for (int i=1;i<=20;i++) // DIFFERENT variable i is declared, hiding the first variable (=1).
    {
        i++;                // The inner-i variable increments: 3, 5, 7, .... 19
    }                       // inner-i is complete, and disappears.  It is no longer active.

    printf("%d",i);         // The original Variable i is printed.
                            // It still has value 10, as originally initialized.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`printf("%d",i);` is not part of the `for` loop, only `i++` is. Indentation is not significant in C, you need to use blocks to group operations together. E.g.

```
for (int i=1;i<=20;i++) 
{
    i++;
    printf("%d",i); 
}
```

Comment: So the for loop executes the statement only next to it due to the absence of blocks and does not execute the printf statement?

Comment: @tirumalaideviramya — yes; only the single statement is in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

In C indentation is not part of the block-structure (like it is in Python).

That means your code is really something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i=10;
  for (int i=1;i<=20;i++)
    i++;  // In loop

  printf("%d",i);  // Not in loop
  return 0;
}
```

Blocks of code have to be delimited with curly-braces `{` and `}`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i=10;
  for (int i=1;i<=20;i++)
  {
    i++;  // In loop
    printf("%d",i);  // Also in loop
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't care about indentation (it only cares about whitespace to the extent that it separates tokens).  If you want multiple statements to be part of a `for` loop (or `while` loop, or `if` statement, etc.) then you need delimit those statements with curly braces:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
  printf( "this statement is part of the loop\n" );
  printf( "this statement is NOT part of the loop\n" );
```

vs.

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
  printf( "this statement is part of the loop\n" );
  printf( "so is this\n" );
}
```

It's generally a good idea to use curly braces even if you only have a single statement:

```
while ( some_condition )
{
  do_something();
}
```

You've also created two separate variables named `i`:

```
int i = 10; // first instance

for ( int i = 1; i <= 20; i++ ) // second instance of i "shadows" the first
```

This works because the `for` loop creates a new *scope*, and you can have variables in different scopes with the same name.  The variable `i` in the `for` loop hides or "shadows" the variable `i` declared at the beginning of the program.  When the `for` loop exits, the `i` declared within it ceases to exist, so you're printing the value of the `i` declared at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is not a necessary part to define a block of code in C.

According to this code, the 'i' that you increment is a different variable than what you want it to be.

The equivalent code is:

```
int main()
{
  int n=10;
  for(int i=1; i<=20;i++)   
    i++;
  printf("%d",n);
}
```

But the required code is:

```
int main()
{
  int i=10;
  for(int i=1; i<=20;i++)
  {
    i++;
    printf("%d",i);
  }
}
```